# Kraken exchange futures API - Generate Authentication Strings - Authentication Error. NodeJs

Tags: javascript, restful-authentication

I'm trying to generate a signed message for private endpoints. From Kraken Futures API documentation steps are:

1. Concatenate postData + nonce + endpointPath
2. Hash the result of step 1 with the SHA-256 algorithm
3. Base64-decode your api_secret
4. Use the result of step 3 to hash the result of step 2 with the 
   HMAC-SHA-512 algorithm
5. Base64-encode the result of step 4

This is what I have done:

```
//Definition of arguments 
const secret = 'SecretGeneratedByKraken...rEqyX3nPw3UURLCu/M'
var nonce =  new Date() * 1000;
const path = 'https://futures.kraken.com/derivatives/api/v3/' + fills;
const signature = getMessageSignature(path,params,secret,nonce);

//Auth function
getMessageSignature = (path, params, secret, nonce) => {
    var message = qs.stringify(params);
    var concat = message + nonce + path;  // 1
    var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    var hash_digest   = hash.update(concat).digest('binary'); // 2
    var secret_decoded = Buffer.from(secret, 'base64'); // 3
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', hash_digest);
    var hmac_digest = hmac.update(secret_decoded, 'binary').digest('base64'); //4 and 5
    return hmac_digest;
}
```

Double checked that I'm passing the right arguments, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the values of `path`, `params`, `secret` and `nonce` and where are they defined?

Comment: Hi, endpoint I'm calling doesn't take any arguments, so `params` is ignored. Edited original post with values for the rest of the arguments.

Comment: where is the doc of the api?